# list comprehension producing result plus gibberish

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I've struggled with this for a few hours now. What I want to do is produce a list that contains numbers with "dB" after them (i.e. 0dB, 1dB, 2dB... Up to 8dB). This is to save me having to manually type in each label for a plot I'm producing.

What I tried first was:

```
 cb.ax.set_yticklabels([x + 'dB' for x in str(np.arange(0, 9))])
```

However, this seemed to mess up my labels completely. So, I went with a longer approach to see exactly what this comprehension was producing by:

```
crange = np.arange(0,9)
crangedb = [x + 'dB' for x in str(crange)]
print crange
print crangedb
```

Output:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]

['[dB', '0dB', ' dB', '1dB', ' dB', '2dB', ' dB', '3dB', ' dB', '4dB', ' dB', '5dB', ' dB', '6dB', ' dB', '7dB', ' dB', '8dB', ']dB']
```

So, while my list of numbers is fine (as expected), once I try to attach dB to each number using a list comprehension, every value is interspersed with either blank values or brackets. My syntax seems to be correct from every page I've Googled, so I must be missing something either super simple or super small.

Comment: Don't you mean `str(x) + 'dB' for x in crange` by chance?

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't know Python. But it looks like you're marching `x` through a string-ified `crange`, rather than marching `x` through `crange`, stringifying it, and adding the `dB` string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting the `np.arange` to a string which is basically `"[1 2 3 4...]"` and then you are iterating over each character. This means that `x=['[','0',' ',...]`. The correct line should be:

```
cb.ax.set_yticklabels([str(x) + 'dB' for x in np.arange(0, 9)])
```

Now you are mapping each item of the `np.ndarray` to a string and concatenate it with `'dB'`.

Comment: Thanks! I came to this conclusion on the drive home. I was worried that writing str(x) would stop it from being variable, but I guess not!

Comment: str(x) returns a new "string" and leaves the variable x as it is.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use `range` instead of `np.arange` for that task:

```
In [105]: [str(i) + 'dB' for i in range(9)]
Out[105]: ['0dB', '1dB', '2dB', '3dB', '4dB', '5dB', '6dB', '7dB', '8dB']
```

**Timing**:

```
In [106]: %timeit [str(i) + 'dB' for i in range(9)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.06 us per loop

In [107]: %timeit [str(i) + 'dB' for i in np.arange(0,9)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 28.6 us per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

There was no need to change `crange` to a string first. When you do that and then iterate over it, you get each character of the literal string representation of that `list`.

`crange`:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
```

`str(crange)`:

```
'[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]'
```

The first element in `crange` is `0`, but the first element in `str(crange)` is the string `'['`. This produces the result you see.

Instead, move the `str()` call around the `x`:

```
crangedb = [str(x) + 'dB' for x in crange]
```

This will produce the desired result. You can also use string formatting:

```
crangedb = ['{}dB'.format(x) for x in crange]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `map`:

```
map(lambda x:"{}db".format(x), change)
```

use range:

```
map(lambda x:"{}db".format(x), range(0,9))
```